# Sorting Multidimensional slices

Tags: sorting, go

Wanted to sort a nested slice (asc to desc) based on int values, however the slice remains unaffected.

Below is the short snippet of what I was trying.

```
type Rooms struct {
    type   string
    total  string
}

CombinedRooms := make([][]Rooms)

// sort by price
for i, _ := range CombinedRooms {
    sort.Slice(CombinedRooms[i], func(j, k int) bool {
        netRateJ, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[i][j].Total)
        netRateK, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[i][k].Total)
        return netRateJ < netRateK
    })
}
```

The Slice CombinedRooms remains unaffected even after the sorting func.

Adding a small example: https://play.golang.org/p/yyGygJyqtkn

Comment: I only wanted to ask if I'm using the sort slice function right

Comment: How do I sort the entire outer slice (CombinedRooms), based on values from []Rooms?

Comment: minimum value in the slice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example https://play.golang.org/p/yyGygJyqtkn is correctly sorting the inner slices, it is printing the same output as the inner slices have the same values. However if you also want to sort CombinedRooms based on inner slices' values, add below code:

```
sort.Slice(CombinedRooms, func(j, k int) bool {
            netRateJ, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[j][0].Total)
            netRateK, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[k][0].Total)
            return netRateJ < netRateK
    })
```

Find working code here https://play.golang.org/p/LLCeJdlE-hM

Answer (score 2):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

type Rooms struct {
    Type  string
    Total string
}

func main() {
    CombinedRooms := [][]Rooms{
        {Rooms{Type: "c", Total: "2"}, Rooms{Type: "b", Total: "1"}, Rooms{Type: "f", Total: "10"}},
        {Rooms{Type: "d", Total: "5"}, Rooms{Type: "a", Total: "0"}},
    }
    fmt.Println(CombinedRooms)

    for i, _ := range CombinedRooms {
        sort.Slice(CombinedRooms[i], func(j, k int) bool {
            netRateJ, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[i][j].Total)
            netRateK, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[i][k].Total)
            return netRateJ < netRateK
        })
    }
    fmt.Println(CombinedRooms)

    sort.Slice(CombinedRooms[:], func(i, j int) bool {
        for x := range CombinedRooms[i] {
            netRateJ, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[i][x].Total)
            netRateK, _ := strconv.Atoi(CombinedRooms[j][x].Total)
            if netRateJ == netRateK {
                continue
            }
            return netRateJ < netRateK
        }
        return false
    })
    fmt.Println(CombinedRooms)
}
```

[playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/F3ba054z14V)

I understand your problem now, above solutions tries to sort the slices by comparing each internal slices elements to order the internal slices in outer slices(in which inner slice elements should be sorted). If you want better than that, i believe you have to flat the slices and sort that.

Comment: Thank you but the other answer was working as expected in multiple conditions